# why can we call sub, function without shared keyword from another form in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have 2 forms

Form 1:

```
 Public Class Form1
     Public Sub MySub()
     End Sub
 End Class
```

Form 2:

```
Public Class Form2
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Form1.MySub()//why??
End Sub
End Class
```

why can i write Form1.MySub() in VB but C# does not

Comment: What do you mean you can't in C#? Can you give an example? As long as it is public function, it can be called outside class

Comment: Form1 is a type name, not an object reference.   VB's default instance feature was created to help programmers move to .NET.  Quite crippling to a programmer's mind, very hard to learn object-oriented programming this way.  Also causes many threading problems.  OOP is what you'll need to learn, no shortcuts in C#.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad: You need an instance to call an instance method - as Hans mentioned, VB creates a default form instance named the same as the form. This is one of the worst 'features' of VB - it truly encourages a lack of understanding.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, yup got it.

Answer (score 3):

The VB.Net compiler provices a [Default Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233839.aspx) for some things. C# does not.

This is done in VB.Net at least partly for compatibility with older VB6-era code, and at least partly not done in C# because C# does not allow naming collisions between types and variables.